# Set attribute selected of particular option of select box using jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a select box with following options

```
select id="box" ><br/>
  option value="1"Same Day<br/>
  option value="5">96<br/>
  option value="4">72<br/>
  option value="3">48<br/>
  option value="2">24<br/>
select>
```

I Want to add attr selected to option value '4' , i know i can show it selected via

```
$("#box").val(4)
```

But this just shows it selected but does not add attribute selected to option 4, what i want is to add attribute selected to option.

Please suggest

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#box').children('option:eq(3)').attr('selected', 'selected');
```

That makes usage of the `eq()` selector which querys the index you specify.

Slightly faster (even if it's more typing) would be the method `.eq()` instead of the selector:

```
$('#box').children('option').eq(3).attr('selected', 'selected');
```

Since `.eq()` uses `array slices` instead of query'ing over Sizzle.
As you notice correctly, both versions start indexing at zero.

Ref.: [:eq](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/), [.eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/)

Comment: Hi Andy,

Soorry but forgot to tell you that select box is dyanamic so i dont know where the option with value 4 will come everytime.I want to trac it using option with value 4.But thanks for great help and even more appreciated if you can get me out of this situtation. :)